# Value of $\int_{0}^1 (1+x+x^2+x^3...{x}^{n-1})*(1+3x+5x^2+...(2n-1)x^{n-1})dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

**Value of $\int_{0}^1 (1+x+x^2+x^3...{x}^{n-1})*(1+3x+5x^2+...(2n-1)x^{n-1})dx$**

**My approach:** I tried writing the first factor as the sum of a gp and solved the second factor as an agp but it made a very complex term which couldn't be simplified further.

Comment: Did you try small values of $n$ and see if you can guess the answer? That might give some clues for how to proceed.

Comment: The integral becomes $$I=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{2j+1}{i+j+1}=n^2$$

Comment: @Quanto Ah, that's a nice way of expressing it. The right equality follows by doing the summation holding $k=i+j+1$ constant, and that explains why my $x^{k}$ coefficient is what I need it to be. $\quad$ Is there another way to show the identity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denote

$$f(x) \equiv 1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k$$

where $f(1) = n$ and $f(0) = 1$. Now consider the second series and rewrite it as
$$1+3x+\cdots+(2n-1)x^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+1)x^k = 2x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kx^{k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k$$

$$ \equiv 2xf'(x) + f(x)$$

Thus, the integral evaluates to

$$\require{cancel} I = \int_0^1 2xf(x)f'(x)+[f(x)]^2\:dx = x[f(x)]^2\Bigr|_0^1 = n^2$$

by product rule.

Comment: +1 Wow. I did notice the $f(x)^2$ pattern, but didn't think we could prove that directly. Very nice.

Comment: @CalvinLin you can also solve the problem by substituting $x^2=t$ and then one of the terms will be substituted as well

Comment: @ShlokJain Can you add that solution?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Try small values of $n$. Use that as a clue to guide the solution.

Show that

- For small values of $n$, the expression equals $n^2$. Let's see how we can show this.
- When we expand the product and do the term wise integral from 0 to 1, we get $ 1 + 2 + ... + (n-1) + n + (n-1) + ... + 2 +  1$.
- Verify the above expression sums to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{(n-1)n}{2} = n^2$.
- To show that the observation about the term wise integral is true, that means that the product of the polynomials has to be:

$$ 1 + 2\times 2 x + 3\times 3x^2 + \ldots \\
+(n-1)\times(n-1)x^{n-2} + n\times n x^{n-1} + (n-1)\times (n+1) x^n + \ldots \\
(2n-2) \times (2) x^{2n-3}+ (2n-1)\times (1)x^{2n-2}$$

- Now that you know the pattern to show, proving this is much easier. You can just multiply them and keep track of the coefficients, or do it via induction.
- Now write up the solution in the forwards way.

If you're stuck, show what you've tried.

Notes

- I'm surprised by this. I'd like to understand why it happens.
- The analogue for $n$ is integrating $ 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \ldots + nx^{n-1}$.
- I'd like to see this extended to $n^3$, but nothing pops out to me.

Comment: yep, I got the expression. But how did you identify the initial $1+2+...+n+n-1..$ series?

Comment: @ShlokJain Try enough small cases and it pops out. EG I made that observation at $n=3$.  It also helps to do it manually instead of just inputting into a calculator.

Comment: Alright, got it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @CalvinLin I have found an interesting solution! I would very much appreciate it if you would look it over and see if it is alright.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=y^2$. Now with $f(y)=y+y^2+...+y^{2n}$ the integral takes the form

$\displaystyle 2\int_0^{1} f(y) f'(y) \ \mathrm{dy} = f^2(1) = n^2$